# Spacing in HTML emails

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I am designing a little app that can email one of 6 design templates with common content.

What is the best (most consistent) way to maintain space and layout of the text (between lines etc.)

We were thinking about using simple `<br>`, but we could lose some flexibility compared to something else. It is a table based layout

Cheers

Comment: If you use paragraphs and set the `line-height` and `padding`, `margin` styles, that should give you control over the spacing between lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yahoo (and possibly other email clients) interpret `<p>` differently than most others--it's hard to make a `<p>` look right in Yahoo without making it look wrong in all the others. In my experience you will get more control over spacing / formatting by using `<br />` along with line-height and of course the font size. You can give a `<br />` tag an inline `line-height` style to tweak spacing even more specifically.

**However:**

- Outlook 2007/2010 tends to ignore the `line-height` property.
- The `margin` styles are used and/or ignored differently by all the email clients. Using `padding` rather than `margin` when possible is a little more reliable.

The best spacing & layout control available in HTML-for-email (which is limited to table-based layouts and inline styles, as you know) is to separate lines / paragraphs of text into different table cells / rows, and control spacing with the `width` & `height` of the `<td>` elements. With this method, you would almost always have `style="border:0; margin:0; padding:0;"`

Answer (score 3):

You should use inline styles in email markup.

Here is an example of how to separate paragraphs consistently within your email build

```
<p style="margin:0 0 15px 0;padding:0;line-height:value;font-size:value">Insert Paragraph information here</p>
<p style="margin:0 0 15px 0;padding:0;line-height:value;font-size:value">Insert Paragraph information here</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Do yourself a favour and take some time to read the article [7 Tips Regarding Margins and HTML Padding in Emails](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/7_tips_and_tricks_regarding_margins_and_padding_in_html_emails/) from Email on Acid.

It's going to help tremendously! And I'm serious...

Comment: Thanks for notifying me of that. I looked for and updated the link. I'm also leaving here the title of the article in case the link breaks again in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The best way today is use a `p` element per line and style that with CSS.

And you should consider to replace most of the table based layout with `div`s and CSS styles (except where you need horizontal elements with the same height, obviously).

My answer would be better if you would state a specific problem like: "How can I achieve this `<insert image here>` with HTML?"